Prove that if there is a necessary condition for P that is not also a sufficient condition for P then there is more than one necessary condition for P
I am looking for verification of the below proof. I'm specifically unsure of the (Q OR P) part
Claim: If Q is a necessary condition for P and Q is not a sufficient condition for P, then there is a necessary condition R for P such that R =/= Q and R =/= P.
Proof:
Let P, Q be predicates such that,

P -> Q
~(Q => P)

Suppose Q is the only necessary condition for P other than P itself i.e.
(P -> R) & (R =/= P) -> R = Q
By totality, for any predicate S,
For all x, S(x) -> P(x) OR for all x,P(x) -> S(x)
Therefore,
For all x, S(x) -> P(x) OR S = Q  (by above supposition)
Given the premise (2),
(Q OR P) =/= Q
Therefore,
(Q OR P) -> P
But,
Q -> (Q OR P)
Therefore,
Q -> P
Contradiction.
Therefore the supposition, (P -> R) & (R =/= P) -> R = Q is false.

Welcome to math SE. What is your question? If you want us to veriffy the proof, tell us which part are you unsure about.

Ah thanks. Yes I am looking for verification. I am unsure about the Q OR P part

Can you explain the jump from "S -> P OR S = Q" to "(Q OR P) =/= Q"?

You're right that is a jump. It has no been shown that (Q OR P) =/= Q. But I believe it is implied by the premise ~(Q -> P)

There is more than one necessary condition for $P$: $Q$ is a necessary condition; $P$ is a necessary condition. Your premise (2) means $\neg (P \leftrightarrow Q)$, so they are different necessary conditions.

Ah yes. Let me rephrase. More than one necessary condition for P that is not equal to P.

Then you'll have to be more precise about what "equal" means, because classical logic doesn't admit three different truth values. (I assume you're working in classical logic given your use of proof by contradiction.)

Sorry I'm not seeing why the above premise implies three truth values. Example Let P(x) := x is a square. There are two distinct necessary condition for P that are not equal to P e.g. 1. 'x has four sides' 2. 'x is equilateral'. By "P equal Q", I mean 'for all x, P(x) <-> Q(x)'

Oh, so they really are predicates and not propositions. I was confused because your post doesn't mention any $x$. But then "totality" doesn't hold either.

Yes they are predicates with omitted variables. Why does totality not hold?

Being even doesn't imply being odd and being odd doesn't imply being even.

Yes but 'x is even' -> 'x is odd' OR 'x is odd -> x is even' does hold

Okay, so you mean $\forall x. (P(x) \to Q(x)) \lor (Q(x) \to P(x))$, not $(\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)) \lor (\forall x. Q(x) \to P(x))$. This is exactly why you should be explicit about quantifiers.

You are right! Sorry

It seems that you are interpreting "$C$ is a necessary condition for $A$" as  equivalent to saying that $A \Rightarrow C$ (on some appropriate reading of the conditional, and the exact reading won't matter for present purposes). And likewise, you are interpreting "$C$ is a sufficient condition for $A$" as  equivalent to saying that $C \Rightarrow A$. OK: let's buy that.
But now note that for any $R$ at all, $P \Rightarrow (P \lor R)$. But, assuming $P$ is contingent, in nearly every case $(P \lor R) \not\Rightarrow P$.
So utterly trivially, by ringing the changes on $R$, any contingent $P$ has innumerable inequivalent necessary-but-not-sufficient conditions.

Note that this assumes things about the universe of discourse.

Or maybe I don't understand your argument, or what we're even trying to prove. Consider $P(x) = x > 0$ in Peano arithmetic; can you name two different predicates implied by $P$? I can only think of $\top$.

Considering a single president doesn't give us enough information to apply the above claim. Let me see if I understand. Consider 1. Q(x) := x > 0; 2. P(x) := x > 1. Are you saying this would be an counterexample to the claim? I.e. P(x) -> Q(x) & ~(Q(x) -> P(x))  & 'there are no other predicates that are implied by P other than Q and P?

predicate* not "president"

No, $P(x) = x > 0$, $Q(x) = \top$.

If this is not a counterexample then what is it suggesting?
